# Building a SQL query to searching between values of 2 DateTimePickers in C#

Tags: c#, sql, between

How can I search in a database using datetimepicker1.text and datetimepicker2.text
I wrote this:

```
"Select * from gelirler where borc_tarihi between" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "'+"'and" + dateTimePicker2.Text, baglanti);
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Try look at your generated sql query and execute it directly in a database manager. If the code you posted are identical to your code you are missing spaces around `and`

Comment: Write your code so it cannot be misunderstood like `var query = "SELET * FROM gelirler WHERE borc_tarihi BETWEEN '"+dateTimePicker1.Text+"'+"' AND '"+dateTimePicker2.Text + "'";`

Comment: Obviously it will not work. Query is not properly written. There should be proper spaces after `*` and `and`. What is `baglanti` by the way.

Comment: Do not create SQL query like this. This is an open hole for hackers to attack your database by SQL-injection. **Always** use `SqlParameter`, like what Gilad Green has answered below.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a problem with the `''` in the query.
It should be

```
var query = "select * from gelirler 
             where borc_tarihi between '"+ dateTimePicker1.Text +"' and '"+ dateTimePicker2.Text +"'"
```

But I'd recommend you to look into [parameterized queries](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Parameterized-Queries-ADO.Net.aspx) all together.. To avoid sql injections.

```
using (SqlCommand command = 
    new SqlCommand("select * from gelirler where borc_tarihi between @begin_time and @end_time", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@begin_time", SqlDbType.Datetime);
    command.Parameters["@begin_time"].Value = datetimePicker1.Text;

    command.Parameters.Add("@end_time", SqlDbType.Datetime);
    command.Parameters["@end_time"].Value = datetimePicker2.Text;
    /* execute the query... */
}
```